# UIImage imageOrientation returns 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am developing an iPhone app in iOS 5. I am using UIImagePickerController to let the user select an image and I need to know the image's orientation.

I have the following code for the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method when the image has been selected:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage = nil;
    UIImage *editedImage = nil;

    // Handle a still image picked from a photo album
    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) 
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        editedImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        originalImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        NSLog(@"editedImage.imageOrientation = %d", editedImage.imageOrientation);
        NSLog(@"originalImage.imageOrientation = %d", originalImage.imageOrientation);

        imageToUse = nil;
        if (editedImage)
            imageToUse = editedImage;
        else 
            imageToUse = originalImage;

    }
}
```

Does anybody know why the imageOrientation values in the NSLog instructions are always 0? I have tried with landscape and portrait images and the result is always the same.

The image selected is not nil, as I am showing it in a UIImageView without problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image orientation is **not** an indication of whether or not the image is in portrait or landscape format.

The orientation specifies how the image data is effectively transformed/rotated before it's displayed.  Typically, for example, the data format of an image taken by a camera is identical, regardless of the orientation of the camera at the time. That is, the an image taken in portrait form could be displayed as a rotated landscape image in its 'raw' form (it depends on the camera of course).

To overcome this, the image metadata is updated with information about the orientation of the camera when the image was taken. Armed with the information, UIUmage can display the image the right way up, by rotating it according to that metadata.

For your need to find out if the image is portrait or landscape in it's final format, just compare the width to the height :)

Tim

Comment: Ok, understood. I will compare the width to the height. Thanks.